# Isomorphism of tangent and cotangent spaces induced by a symplectic structure on a manifold

Tags: symplectic-geometry

If $(M^{2n}, \omega^2)$ is a symplectic manifold, then for each tangent vector $v \in T_xM$ for some $x \in M$ we may associate a $1$-form $\omega_v^1 \in T_x^* M$ by $\omega_v^1(u) = \omega^2(u,v)$.

The map carrying a vector to it's associated $1$-form is an isomorphism. My issue is with proving this.

Showing that it is injective is simple enough by looking at the kernal. It is surjectivity that I am stuck on. I'm trying to show that given an arbitrary $1$-form on $T_x M$, there is a vector, such that the image of this vector under the map constructed above, is the form.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the title of the post to mark it as solved, instead accept the answer giving the solution.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't yet noticed that.

Comment: By the way this also gives you an isomorphism between the tangent *bundle* and the cotangent bundle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can show that it is injective, then it is surjective since both spaces have the same dimension.